# Cannot call function in Angular 2 template using PrimeNG data table

Tags: angular, primeng

My app runs Angular 2.4.1 and PrimeNG 1.1.1.
It uses a data table like so:

```
 <p-dataTable *ngIf="selectedWebSearch" [value]="selectedWebSearch.results" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedSearchResult"
```

The columns shall be rendered dynamically, thus I use a template:

```
<p-column *ngFor="let property of properties" header="{{property}}">
         <template let-col let-rowData="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                id{{rowData.getId()}} <-- does not work
                id{{rowData.id}} <-- does workwork
          </template>
 </p-column>
```

I wonder why calling the method `getId()` which exists does lead to this exception:

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.context.rowData.getId is not a function`

In contrast, using the member variable prints the right value.

Any ideas?

***UPDATE:***

Another example:

I have a main component that has a member variable `selectedWebSearch`. One web search has a name amongst other properties.

For testing purposes I can print its name as output:

`{{selectedWebSearch?.name}}`

Now I add a method `getHello` to the web search class that returns a simple string "hello" and print it like so

`{{selectedWebSearch?.getHello()}}´

Then I receive this error trace:

> TypeError: self.context.selectedWebSearch.getHello is not a function
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_SemanticSearchComponent0.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:1451)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12592)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12739)

Any ideas?